# Mutiplos projetos em MVC e WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Estou procurando se existe algum modelo de projeto que envolva múltiplos projetos MVC e WebAPI. Na solução que eu estou pensando em projetar (caso seja possível) uma solução de gerenciamento de conteúdo para vários clientes e estou pensando da seguinte maneira:

Queria ter um projeto Pai onde ele seria o core "núcleo" da minha aplicação e o restante seriam sub-projetos onde vou chama-los de "módulos" no qual, esses módulos poderiam ser versionados. Vamos imagina o seguinte senário:

Projeto Principal em MVC aonde eu gerencio os usuários e clientes. Ai eu preciso desenvolver um modulo de gerenciamento de Noticia, outro de gerenciamento Fotos.

**SG.MVC** -> *Master Page, pagina inicial e gerenciamento de módulos*

**SG.Modulo.Core** -> *Interfaces necessária para o desenvolvimento de modulo e incluilo na aplicação MVC*

**SG.Modulo.Noticia.V1**

**SG.Modulo.Noticia.V2**

**SG.Modulo.Foto.V1**

**SG.Modulo.Portifolio.V1**

**Como eu poderia compilar esses módulos em projetos separados** e depois **injetar** esses módulos na aplicação principal, não sendo necessário recompilar e adaptar a aplicação principal toda vez que tiver que incluir um novo módulo entregando um projeto único de forma dinâmica, um exemplo seria um wordpress, joomla onde podem ser inseridos módulos.

> Pensei em buscar os módulos (compilados em **dll**) salvos em uma pasta, ou então gerenciar a existência desse módulo em um banco de dados mostrando onde a **dll** de cada módulo está localizada. Qualquer luz no fim do túnel será bem vindo.

Answer (score 3):

Já trabalhei em uma empresa que possuía um ERP enorme e eles tinham uma divisão muito bem feitas dos diversos módulos do sistema. A estrutura que eles utilizavam era basicamente assim:

- TFS era utilizado para controle de versão, e confesso que era muito mais agradável que utilizar Git;
- Cada módulo do sistema possuía sua própria solution do Visual Studio e todos estavam no controle de versão;
- Módulos base compilavam para bibliotecas (DLL);
- Módulos base tinham um diretório de saída de build customizado e que era específico para todos eles, uma pasta que não era versionada, ou seja, quando um módulo base era compilado, uma DLL era gerada nessa pasta e o mesmo valia para todos os outros módulos base, no final você tinha uma pasta com todas as DLLs básicas para o funcionamento dos módulos, e essa era a grande chave da história, pois dessa forma essas DLLs podiam ser facilmente referenciados pelos módulos principais, sem que houvem problemas relacionados a diretórios.

Bom, essa é uma forma interessante de abordar esse problema e á a forma que eu utilizaria caso precisasse montar um projeto grande e de maneira que pudesse ser facilmente expandido.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui injetar Class Libraries em MVC usando [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/). No entanto, alguns avisos precisam ser dados:

- O Unity conflita com o ASP.NET Identity. Nunca consegui resolver a configuração para funcionar;
- As *Views* precisam existir no módulo principal;
- A configuração de rotas precisa ser feita utilizando [`[Route]`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).